# RESTful way to merge resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Given two resources

- `http://example.com/places/1`
- `http://example.com/places/2`

How should the endpoint look like to merge both resources into a single resource? Ideally after the merge only 1 resource will remain.

At first glance I could do a `PUT` to `http://example.com/places/1` with `params[:src_id] = 2`. Which would merge the attributes from the second resource into the first and delete the the second resource. Does anyone else have a better approach?

Note that I'm using Rails which doesn't support the http `MERGE` verb so that's out of the question.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d446392f76c063d9f04396a1d3ca9e314a521671 Rails does seem to support MERGE since 2010. Not sure when it made it into a release though. Also not sure if it would be appropriate to adapt it from webdav context to non-webdav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a new controller `PlacesMergeController` with a new and create action. In the new action, you would have a form asking which places to merge. The form will do a POST request to the create action, where you do the actual merging. Depending on the complexity of the logic you could also have a PlacesMerge model (non-AR!).

This approach should give you maximum flexibility in terms of handling source/target of the merge operation - and it's easily maintainable.

Comment: +1: Merging feels like a POST to me given that a dedicated verb is unavailable.