# REST Merge Resources - Multiple updates on PUT

Tags: rest, merge

I do not believe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878712/restful-way-to-merge-resources) fully answers the question.

**Situation**

- Endpoint exposes a single resource, Ids are unique.
- Names are unique but can change.
- External applications can and do store references to resource ids.

**The problem**

Sometimes duplicate resources are created and end up being referenced.

**Solution**

Expose an endpoint that allows resources to be "merged". This would do the following:

1. Mark 'xyz' (the resource being phased out) as being a duplicate of 'abc' (the resource being kept).
2. Update 'abc' to be what the merge resource should look like.
3. Any GET to retrieve 'xyz' will result in a 302 redirect to 'abc'

**The Question**

How would one do this restfully? I wanted to do something like:

```
PUT http://endpoint/resource/{id1}/merge/{id2}

{
    //new merged resource
}
```

Where `id1 =` the resource being kept and `id2 =` the resource being. Alternatively this could be visa versa if it makes more sense.

However my concern is that the act of merging will update both resources on a PUT. Does this break the rules and is there a better, prescribed way to do this?

Comment: Did the accepted answer work well?

Comment: @Moriarty - Yes but in my case I used the PUT verb instead of POST. See my comment below the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, the RESTful paradigm is great for giving people guidelines on how your API probably behaves, but forcing everything you can into it doesn't result in a better developer experience.

I would much rather see well-documented POST actions for everything beyond the standard four verbs. Here's my vote:

```
POST http://endpoint/resources/{id1}/merge
  {
     "merge_id": {id2}
  }
```

This also leaves you free to support a multi-id version, if that were commonplace.

```
POST http://endpoint/resources/{id1}/merge
  {
    "merge_ids": [
      {id2}, {id3}, {id4}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: This is fairly similar to what I came up with in my head last night, and also similar to @Lutz's answer. The only change I would make is to use PUT rather than a POST as the command would not generate a new resource and it would be idempotent.

Answer (score 2):

What about a "merge" resource?

```
POST http://endpoint/merges/
{
  "merge_ids": [
    11, 12, 13, 14
  ]
}

201 Created
Location: http://endpoint/merges/486C23F8-A5FD-11E4-A65F-14CD89BEA664
```

This resource would have a separate state which could be queried:

```
GET http://endpoint/merges/486C23F8-A5FD-11E4-A65F-14CD89BEA664

200 OK
{
  "merge_ids": [
    11, 12, 13, 14
  ],
  "state": "merged"
}
```

A request for the primary resource would return it, a request for any of the secondary (merged) resources would return a `301` with a `Location` header of the primary resource.

Comment: At first glance I thought this was a good idea how ever on second thought not so. The issue I have is that a consumer of the first resource now has another resources to worry about (yes I appreciate the location header). Also the implementation has to expose the two resources. Now instead just take what you had suggested but make it a post on to the original endpoint then that I think would be fine. In the end I went for @Elliot's suggestion which is similar. I wanted to maintain the original record that was being merged to.